# Why is my SVG cropped when reloaded from a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

When loading an image from URL, FabricJS displays the image accurately. But when exporting to SVG, clearing the canvas an importing the SVG again, the image is changed drastically.

When testing with the [wikimedia logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg), after one reload only the top left quarter is visible and after the second reload, only the top red circle remains. What causes this change in the image?

### code to reproduce issue:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg", (object) => {
  object.forEach((object) => {
    canvas.add(object);
  });
});

function reload() {
  let svg = canvas.toSVG();
  canvas.clear();
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, (object) => {
    object.forEach((object) => {
      canvas.add(object);
    });
  });

  console.log(`experted SVG: ${svg}`);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="reload()">reload</button>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
</body>
```

### After first reload:

[image]

### After second reload:

[image]

When looking at a [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/fTKm2oP7/) the dimensions of the two `clipPaths` of the image get enormous. My guess is they cover the rest of the image, but I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: I want to develop an editor where the user can save the image and load it later to continue editing.

Comment: removing the clippath from the wikimedia logo solves the problem. This now looks like a bug to me.